# CardView rounded corners not showing up in Android preview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

### My problem

My card views defined through XML are **not showing their proper rounded corners (they are being covered by its subviews) in Android studio preview**.

**Although it shows up fine after rendering in the simulator**, I fear that this "glitch" may be a symptom of me doing something wrong or forgetting some critical attribute. And even if it wasn't a symptom of a deeper problem, could anyone offer any insight on how to fix this aesthetic error?

Could anyone weigh in on this?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"

    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:src="@color/red"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

### Android studio screenshot

[image]

### Android emulator screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in the generated preview is that the content inside the `CardView` is not *clipped* to the bounds of the `CardView`, so the corner's you see are corners of the `ImageView`, which is actually clipped when you run on emulator/device.

If you really want to generate the *real-like* preview, you can try this workaround.

1. Add a stub drawable with the corner radius you want.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle">

     <corners android:radius="20dp" />
     <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

   </shape>
   ```
2. Then set it as the background of the `ImageView` under the `tools:` namespace.

   ```
   <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:src="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
     tools:src="@drawable/test" />
   ```

Android Studio supports a variety of XML attributes in the [`tools:` namespace](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html) that enable design-time features (such as `src` of the `ImageView` to display when in preview mode).

Answer (score 0):

here rounded corners show normally with your code. My test phone is Android 7.1. so I think you should clear the cache of your phone and install this app again. or maybe you should increase the value of

> app:cardCornerRadius

then test it again.

Comment: Does it show up normally in Android studio preview too?

Comment: @AlanSTACK, here in Android studio preview, I can see CardView's rounded corners, but it is hidden by AppCompatImageView.